# Implementing search functionality using sphnix

Tags: search, full-text-search, sphinx

I need to implement search functionality for my project.after exploring some full-text search engines.I found sphinx search appropriate for my project.

After some understanding i found that i need to feed data to be searched into DB,then indexer pulls data from Db and build indexes.after that searchd uses that index to answer the query.am having hard time installing it in my Ubuntu machine and i don't know how to proceed after that.I didn't find any sample project to look into.I have list of html files to be searched for keyword which user gives.

My first questions are

1) Any complete guide to implement sphinx search?

2) How do i insert html files into Db.Is searching through html files are supported in sphnix?

3) My project is completely done only with javascript. No server side as of now.To integrate 
this searching functionality into my project.Do i need to use any API to communicate with the main code?

Sorry for such long and asking too many questions.Am beginner programmer and figuring out all these seems hard.

Could any one help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not really. Because it can never cover all the points. The manual has a good installation guide, otherwise look on line for tutorials.
2. You dont HAVE to insert them into a DB. Sphinx can index other sources. TSV or XML files in particular. Or even a script that just outputs XML for indexing (so it reads files, and outputs new XML that Sphinx indexes) Or you could just insert filenames into database, and sphinx can fetch the content from the files itself.

   Or can use Real Time Indexes, where you 'insert' the data directly into the sphinx index, no intermedite   datebase/file etc needed

   Yes sphinx can directly index html content - it can strip the raw HTML to leave just the text to index `strip_html`
3. Yes sphinx would need to run on a server.

   If your data is modest (couple of MB), could just index on the client - the index the client would have to download would be small. 
   https://github.com/reyesr/fullproof

   Could also use something like http://indexden.com/ which provides 'sphinx as a service' :)